# Is there a better way to find the location of a minimum element in an Array?

Tags: ruby, arrays, max

Right now I have

```
def min(array,starting,ending)
  minimum = starting
  for i in starting+1 ..ending
    if array[i]<array[minimum]
      minimum = i
    end    
  end

return minimum
end
```

Is there a better "implementation" in Ruby? This one still looks c-ish.
Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by "better" ? More efficient or that which requires less lines of code?

Comment: Sorry I meant to say a better implementation in ruby.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to find the index of the minimal element, you can use `Enumerable#enum_for` to
get an array of items-index pairs, and find the minimum of those with `Enumerable#min` (which will also be the minimum of the original array).

```
% irb
irb> require 'enumerator'
#=> true
irb> array = %w{ the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog }
#=> ["the", "quick", "brown", "fox", "jumped", "over", "the", "lazy", "dog"]
irb> array.enum_for(:each_with_index).min
#=> ["brown", 2]
```

If you want to bound it to specific array indices:

```
irb> start = 3
#=> 3
irb> stop = 7
#=> 7
irb> array[start..stop].enum_for(:each_with_index).min
#=> ["fox", 0]
irb> array[start..stop].enum_for(:each_with_index).min.last + start
#=> 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically that's the best you can do, though you can write it a bit more succinctly:

```
def minval(arr)
    arr.inject {|acc,x| (acc && acc < x ? acc : x)}
end
```

Comment: I think the OP wanted the index of the minimum value, rather than the value itself.  Which makes it a bit harder to use inject.

Comment: And, you don't even need to use anything other than: arr.min to get the minimum value.

Comment: Although this is clever, I cannot use it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simpler way and it works for me in ruby 1.9.2:

```
a = [6, 9, 5, 3, 0, 6]
a.find_index a.min
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the standard algorithm for finding the minimum element in an array, it can be better by having the array already be sorted before this function is called.

Otherwise I can't find a more efficient way of doing this. Specifically, linear time in big O notation is the best we can do.

Comment: Im sorry I meant to say Is there a better implementation for the same algorithm in Ruby?

Answer (score -1):

If this isn't simply an academic question, why not just use Ruby's native `sort` method? It's implemented using a quicksort algorithm, and is considered to be pretty fast.

```
a = [3, 4, 5, 1, 7, 5]
a.sort![0] # => 1
```

Comment: On "large" lists, that's going to be far more expensive. O(n*log(n)) instead of O(n)

Comment: The time increases by a large factor and I cannot integrate the subroutine into another method like Selection_Sort.

Comment: Agreed. I was thinking that for some reason a sort had to happen.